# Btrim function is not working properly in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, controller

Here, I have a problem in the value from `trim()` function  in `PostgreSQL`:

`Ruby` code:

```
    if(this.modelName=="ClientOffice")
       {    this.params="model_name="+this.modelName+"&action_name="+this.actionName+"&
find_condition=btrim(clients_corporate_billings.id,' ') %3D 
btrim('"+validString('populateValue0','text')+"',' ')
  & object_id="+this.objectId;
      }
```

---

```
 &action_name="+this.actionName+"
    &find_condition=btrim(clients_corporate_billings.id,' ') %3D
     btrim('"+validString('populateValue0','text')+"',' ')
```

In above code, `btrim` is `function` of PostgreSQL for trimming but it gives/produce error.

Comment: Error ::  PGError: ERROR: function pg_catalog.btrim(integer, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: ...ient_offices".clients_corporate_billing_id WHERE (trim(clien...

Comment: That's quite alright - I also can't find a function "btrim" with a first parameter of type integer. You have to cast or convert the first argument to text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html).

> **Function:** btrim(string text [, characters text])
>   **Return Type:** text
>   **Description:** Remove the longest string consisting only of characters in characters (a space by default) from the start and end of string
>   **Example:** btrim('xyxtrimyyx', 'xy')
>   **Result:** trim

---

So you need to cast as text:

> &find_condition=btrim(clients_corporate_billings.id**::text**,' ') %3D

Comment: Glad we could help.  PostgreSQL errors are pretty descriptive.  If there's ever a problem with a native function that you know exists, it's generally due to the arguments passed in.  If you ever see a message regarding `typecast`, it gives you a big help in knowing what to look for.

Comment: hi @vol7ron can you plz help me, why does this `btrim('xyxtrimyyx', 'yzz')` display this `xyxtrimyyx`

Comment: @ziMtyth it seems like you need to ask a new question and describe the full extent of your problem case, what you’re doing, and what you’ve tried

Comment: @vol7ron indeed, I did that and I got an answer thanks anyway  =)